# how to retrieve data from firebase on java desktop (Netbeans)

Tags: java, firebase, netbeans

I have an Android application that save data to Firebase, then I want to display the data using Java Desktop via Netbeans. I've made a program to display data but no data is displayed on Netbeans. Is my program wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://login-register-8c85b.firebaseio.com/")
                    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Kuliah\\Pascasarjana\\Bismillah Tesis\\Netbeans\\FirebaseServer\\src\\firebaseserver\\login-register-8c85b-firebase-adminsdk-3ibrz-91ac905e4d.json")))
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);

            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
           DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("user").child("Fha6pl58MgQEYGCa0QFRjCjLyVW2");

           ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    FirebaseServer post = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseServer.class);
                    System.out.println(post);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the printStackTrace